# Different QWebView objects produce identical output for same urls

Tags: qt, pyqt, qwebview

I found that if we load one url with different QWebView objects parallely, we will get identical output: only one of this QWebView will make real request. Here is example:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView

def load_and_print(url):
    view = QWebView()
    view.load(QUrl(url))
    def on_ready(ok):
        print(view.page().mainFrame().documentElement().toPlainText())
    view.loadFinished.connect(on_ready)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    # This url outputs random number:
    url = 'https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=100&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
    load_and_print(url)
    load_and_print(url)

    app.exec_()

    # output:
    # 39
    # 39
```

How can we get "fair", unique output for each QWebView object, If url is the same?

PyQt 5.4, windows 7

Comment: You should specify used Python, PyQt, OS versions.

Comment: Try disabling caching pages. In C++ it is made by using:QWebSettings::globalSettings
()-
>setMaximumPagesInCache
(0);
72 QWebSettings::globalSettings
()-
>setObjectCacheCapacities
(0, 0, 0);
I believe in python there is something similar.

Comment: @MKarol Just as an additional comment (was wrongly posted as answer before): I do not see this behavior on Python 3.4.2, PySide 1.2.2 (Qt 4.8), Windows 7 all 64 bit, even if the objectcachecapacities are set to something nonzero. So it may be implementation specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to disable cache:

```
view.page().settings().setObjectCacheCapacities(0, 0, 0)
```